# Associating a marker (dot) with calendar control

Tags: iphone, custom-controls, ios4, ios-simulator

My Application requires the calendar control and i had downloaded the custom calendar control from the below given link.

http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244

Now the thing we want to do is put a dot in the tile for the dates which has some data associated with it. How can I implement it using the above calendar?

Please Give Your Suggestions

Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the thing working. Actually i got the solution after a week by myself so if anyone interested is knowing the method then please let me know guys.. i would be happy to help.

basically it is about making a few changes.

Few changes are very hard to put here so if anyone is interested then i would help him/her.

Thanks anyways

Comment: It is good to post it in Github and provide the URL over here ,so that one can see it.